# Git Feature Branch Merge into Master Branch

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, merge

We have below git structure:

1. master branch used for uat
2. develop branch forked from master but deployed on dev branch

Developers work on feature branch forked from develop branch(feature1,feature2) and ultimately merge it into develop branch. We generally then merge develop branch into master branch to promote the changes further.
Before merging feature1 into develop we take pull of develop to avoid merging issues so sometimes feature1 branch also includes commits from feature2 which was already merged into develop. This creates an issue when I have to move particular feature changes(feature1) directly into master. Currently we are cherry picking the commits to achieve this. Is there any simple and reliable method to merge only feature1 changes into master

Comment: Revert the feature2 merge, merge into main, revert the revert.

Comment: But seriously, if this is an issue then your workflow / architecture is wrong. You're hitting yourself in the face.

Comment: @matt any other option other than reverting feature2

Comment: This feature → develop → master thing is a typical flow that should work if you restrict yourself to merges. Mixing merges and cherry-picking is like mixing… well, mixing chemicals that in isolation are fine but if mixed they can harm you.

Comment: Don't merge feature2 into develop if you don't want it in master. Or merge / rebase _each feature_, not develop, into master. Basically, as I said, you have an architecture / workflow that isn't what you want and now you're fighting it all the time.

Comment: @matt I think OP's scenario makes more sense if you think of it this way: `feature1` was originally just a regular feature slated to go into `develop`, but now they decided it should be a hotfix to production instead, and needs to go to `master` instead of `develop`. (I think worded that way you can see there is no problem with `feature2` going into `develop`. This is a normal thing that happens.)

Comment: Totally @TTT, if you think of it as a hotfix you can just use basic git flow. But that is what I mean by "merge / rebase _each feature_".

Answer (score 2):

> Currently we are cherry picking the commits to achieve this.

Conceptually, that is the correct thing to do in this case. Fortunately, you can improve it a bit.

If you have just 1 commit the cherry-pick is trivial. If you have more than 1 commit, you could cherry-pick them individually in order, or use the range syntax:

```
git cherry-pick <first-commit>~1..<last-commit>
```

Or, you can use an advanced rebase command, perhaps even on the same branch. Note that a rebase is essentially a series of cherry-picks. IMHO this would be the best "simple and reliable method" that you seek, especially considering that you'll most likely want to rewrite your current branch instead of creating a new branch. (The reason for this is explained below.) Using your example branches the advanced rebase command would be:

```
git rebase develop feature1 --onto master
```

In words that command says:

> Take all commits on `feature1` that are not reachable by `develop`, and replay them, one by one, in order, on top of `master`.

The result would be that each of the commits that are new to `feature1` would be cherry-picked in order on top of `master`, and it would rewrite `feature1` so that you can now merge it into `master`. See [eftshift0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76111386/184546) for more details about this syntax and graphical examples.

**Why use the same branch instead of creating a new branch?**

In general, in the final version of your long term history, it's best to avoid duplicate copies of commits, when possible. This means that as a rule of thumb you should merge instead of cherry-picking commits that are already merged into long lived branch. Note that in your example, the commits you would cherry-pick are not already merged into a "long lived branch", since you didn't merge `feature1` into `develop` yet. If you had already merged into `develop`, and then realized you needed them in `master` prior to when you can merge `develop` into `master`, then you would have had no choice but to cherry-pick or rebase those commits with duplicate copies. In your case though, you can avoid this by doing the cherry-pick or rebase described above, merging into `master`, and then immediately merging `master` back into `develop`. In this way you will avoid having duplicate copies for `feature1` in both `master` and `develop`.

Essentially you should treat your `feature1` merge into `master` as a hotfix, and after any hotfix into `master` you should immediately merge `master` back down into `develop`.

Answer (score 0):

Except in special cases where you can indeed merge 'dev' in a **long** feature branch because doing other way is too difficult, the easier way to fix merge conflics of a feature branch is to rebase it onto the target branch (here 'dev').

That let you the possibility to fast-forward or squash merge (could be good if you have only 1 commit in the feature branch) or do a normal merge commit to materialize the feature branch merge.

And that way you could more easily back port your feature in master by doing a 'rebase onto'.

Comment: Ok.. will try this out

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by rebasing:

```
git rebase the-current-base-branch feature-branch --onto a-different-branch
```

If you used `feature1` as the base for starting `feature2` and you want to put that on top of `main`. Before rebase you might have something like:

```
* Z second commit feature2 (feature2)
* Y first commit feature2
| * Merge of feature1 into blah (blah)
|/|
* | Second commit of feature1 (feature1)
* | First commit of feature1
|/
* Another commit in blah
* Some commit in blah
| * Another commit in main branch (main)
|/
* Some commit in main branch
```

Then you do:

```
git rebase feature1 feature2 --onto main
```

And you end up with this:

```
* Merge of feature1 into blah (blah)
|\
* | Second commit of feature1 (feature1)
* | First commit of feature1
|/
* Another commit in blah
* Some commit in blah
| * Second commit feature2 (feature2)
| * First commit feature2
| * Another commit in main branch (main)
|/
* Some commit in main branch
```

Comment: This is the way I would go too, and I added an answer which references yours. Some tweaks though- I think you have `feature1` and `feature2` swapped, since OP states `feature2` is already merged into `develop` and it's `feature1` that needs to go to `master` instead of `develop`. Also, I think the base for `feature1` should probably be `develop` instead of `feature2`. (You may wish to consider using the rebase command in my answer with before and after examples. Note that `feature2` is already merged into `develop`, which would be nice to show in the graph.)